# Passed-in prop used to initialize a useState hook gets updated when calling the hook's updater method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Given the following code:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ myObj }) => {
    const [myStatefulObj, setMyStatefulObj] = useState(myObj.subObj)

    const handleChange = () => {
        const updatedObj = { newProperty: Math.random() }
        setMyStatefulObj(updatedObj) // myObj is updated too!
    }

    return <div />
}
```

I am trying to initialize a new local prop with `useState`, and hydrating its initial value with a prop that is passed in from a parent component.

When I update my prop using `setMyStatefulObj` everything works fine, except that it's also updating the prop that's passed into the component.

This is an undesired side effect and one I haven't come across before.

The prop that is getting passed in is from a parent that creates it with a selector from `react-redux`'s `useSelector` hook.

There are no actions being dispatched or anything, but simply logging the value of the `myObj` prop shows that it is indeed being updated every time the local `setMyStatefulObj` method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are describing doesn't make sense and I was not able to reproduce it. Maybe you could create a snippet and share it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that was caused by the hooks function.

I have created a simple example in [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-flower-i2465) as you said, and it obviously not reproduced. You can edit this sandbox and try to simulate your situation maybe you can find the root cause.

But since you are using redux, I would suggest you to use `useSelector` to select the state you need inside hooks function, then you would not have this kind of concern, and it will have better performance(if you pass the prop, every time myObj changes the hooks component will re-render).